# How to improve WinJS Pivot Control performance

Tags: windows-phone-8.1, winjs, uwp

I have an application based around Pivot Control, where user can dynamically add the pivot items based on the content they would like to see. Each content basically contains a listview that is containing the data retreived asynchronously via winjs xhr object.

The listviews in different pivots might contain different amount of items and while the number is relatively low (up to 20) the performance even with animations is acceptable, but as soon as one of the listview has more than 100 items the sliding between the pivot items get really painful to watch, it just lags.

I've tried to optimize the application via

- modifying the listview itemTemplate not through the binding template, but very basic content rendering.. that has helped A LOT for the listview to render quickly
- disabling the animations in WinJS.UI

Even though the above measures have helped quite a lot, I can still see that while navigating from the pivot that contains a lot of items in the listview, the application hangs (does I don't know what) and then it slides to the next pivot. This might last up to 5 seconds and it's really not the best UX.

Just to make it clear, the content to show in the listview is being fetched at the time the application is being initialized, so the performance issue is definitely not caused by any possible XHR requests.

Could please anyone tell me what is happening behind the slide-out/slide-in operations as all I would do is just to set the content to dispay=none ! but it takes ages to display the next pivot item.

Thank you!

Comment: I'm not as good with WinJS as C#/XAML, but have you checked to see if your listviews are virtualizing properly?  Can you check to see if every item is getting created rather than just a subset?  This was very common in XAML when people would put their ListView in a ScrollViewer, making the ListView extremely large (super large height) and causing it to render everything.

Comment: Thanks. Well I'm quite sure that the listview generates every item but I don't think it's the problem here as I've optimized it so it takes less than a second but the problem is that once it's rendered on the pivot item, and you swipe to the next one, it hesitates, then it shows the new pivot item but it seems like it's still doing something with the content of the previous one (the one with large listview) and only then it renders the content of the new pivot item. I'd have thought that once its content is rendered and swiped to the next pivot, it would just display to none to the parent node

Comment: You might need to show some code, because I don't see that behavior when I try it on the old WinJS playground.  I took their Pivot sample (that contains ListViews in each PivotItem) and just copy-pasted the existing data multiple times so that there were 350 items in the inbox pivot.  I didn't see any issues with freezing.  It barely stuttered when it loaded the data the first time it displayed.  Afterwards, there was no stutter (Edge browser).  
http://winjs.azurewebsites.net/#pivot

Comment: you're right in those samples it works quite well. In emulator the application works quite well, the problem is a bit on my Lumia 830 where it takes time, but again, it's not the listview rendering rather than pivot navigating from a item with a large listview to a next item and that might be even empty and still will take long time to render...I'll try to put up something meaningful..